# How you Hide/Show a table's borders in Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide and display a border in a table using JS or Jquery but am unable to do it, any assistance please.

```
<table Id="IdTable" name="nameTable">
    <tr><td>Name</td><td>Age</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Joseph</td><td>35</td></tr>
</table>
```

I've tried

```
document.getElementById("IdTable").style.border=1;

$("#IdTable").css.apply("border", "1");
```

I'm doing it so that you turn on and off the borders.

Comment: Do you need it on a click of button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`border` is an attribute. so try

```js
document.getElementById("IdTable").border = 1;
```

```html
<table Id="IdTable" name="nameTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Age</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Joseph</td>
    <td>35</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: table border as an attribute is deprectaed.

Answer (score 0):

border is attribute so use as

```js
//document.getElementById("IdTable").style.border=1;


$('#IdTable').css('border', '1px solid');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table Id="IdTable" name="nameTable">
    <tr><td>Name</td><td>Age</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Joseph</td><td>35</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Table border as an attribute is deprecated